# Doing a static type checking at method level, python

Tags: python

I'm very new to python and I have following dooubt.

Lets say I have class named `TestRequest` and `TestResponse`. And there is a method named `testStatic` in another class.

I wish `testStatic` method accepts only `TestRequest` as its parameter and returns only `TestReponse` object as response.

Is that possible in python?

I'm from java background where I can write like this:

```
public TestResponse testStatic(TestRequest request)
{
    return response
}
```

how to achieve the same in python?

Thanks

Comment: What should happen if someone passes a different type?

Comment: @eumiro: I wish python to throw the error automatically as Java do. Is that possible?

Comment: Python is a dynamically typed language; by definition it does not have static typechecking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't get "compile-time" type-checking, like in Java, but you can do it at runtime by asserting that an object is an instance of a class, like this:

```
def testStatic(self, request):
    assert isinstance(request, TestRequest)
    ...
```

(But as others have pointed out, this isn't something you'd normally do in Python.  Look up "Duck Typing".)

Comment: thanks. But no way to assure that `testStatic` will return `TestResponse`?

Comment: @batman: Your unit tests for testStatic could perform a similar assertion on its return value.

Comment: Except for a very few corner cases there's no much point in runtime typecheking, and it often ends up being just harmful...

Comment: Don't do this. If you're worried about your own code, unit test. If you're worried about 3rd party code, make better friends.

Comment: @detly: this should be a quote